# Image upload with Carrierwave and Jcrop generates InvalidAuthenticityToken message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, carrierwave, jcrop

I have a Rails 4 form that uses both Carrierwave and Jcrop to upload an image for an avatar. I've already done this successfully for one profile type. It works fine when uploading an avatar image or skipping the image upload.

But on my new form, whenever I actually add an image and submit, I get `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in StudentProfilesController#create`. Yet if I skip image upload, everything works fine and the profile is created.

I've read quite a few posts on this, and they all talk about a hidden form field with the authenticity token, and yet I've not been able to find this in my rendered form anywhere, either this one, or the ones that work entirely correctly. All I have is, in the header, the following (token replaced with x's):

```
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="xxxxxxx" name="csrf-token" />
```

Some other important facts: there's a good deal of jquery fiddling going on with the avatar crop selection (which I'm doing locally with Jcrop on the selected image before upload). But that's also true of the other profile type where everything works correctly. The one thing that is notably different here is that the form is set for "remote," that is:

```
<%= form_for(@student_profile, html: { remote: true, multipart: true } ) do |f| %>
```

In general, I'm not expecting anyone to debug my code. I'm just trying to figure out how this image upload component is somehow overwriting my authenticity token. Am I wrong that there's no hidden authenticity_token field in my form? If so, where can I find it? If not, how does this get uploaded? Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

In the session dump, I also see this (token replaced with x's):

```
_csrf_token: "xxxxxxxx"
session_id: "cb2076df134740cf2ba14e38b2ed78c6"
```

The token shown there is a match for the one in the meta tag above. Does this mean the token is getting sent?

Lastly, the request parameters shows the following:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "student_profile"=>{"crop_x"=>"318.54545454545456",
 "crop_y"=>"902.5454545454546",
 "crop_w"=>"1698.909090909091",
 "crop_h"=>"1698.909090909091",
 "first_name"=>"Zachary",
 "last_name"=>"Bolton",
 "nickname"=>"Zach",
 "date_of_birth"=>"",
 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb9101c1058 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/RackMultipart20140218-4819-mkwye0>,
 @original_filename="Zach.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"student_profile[avatar]\"; filename=\"Zach.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Add student"}
```

**Update**

Ancient history at this point, but I did use Remotipart as recommended and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think it's because you are trying to send a multipart form with ajax, which doesn't work "out the box". You need something like Remotipart https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Easy-Ajax-file-uploads-with-Remotipart - I've not used it myself though.

Comment: Thanks @veritas1. That was just the issue. Much appreciated!